# Dynamically adding table rows with ids and classes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that has one row I have a function that adds a table row when a button is pressed. However the new rows that are added do not have the same ids as the first row (which I need). The script to add table rows I got from Stack Overflow however I am new to jQuery and I'm a little bit stuck.

I can see that the td contenteditable being appended to the table rows. However if I put an id in with it so it's `td id='task'` then every cell on the row has that id.

This is the function that adds the table row and td

```
$("#project-table").each(function () {
         var tds = '<tr>';
         jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
             tds += '<td contenteditable="true"></td>';
         });
         tds += '</tr>';
         if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
             $('tbody', this).append(tds);
         } else {
             $(this).append(tds);
         }
     });
```

This is the table row I want to duplicate (with the ids for each td intact):

```html
<tr>
    <td id="task_name" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td id="brief" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td id="assigned_to" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td id="hours_to_complete" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td id="status" contenteditable="true"></td>
</tr>
```

So in conclusion I want my add table row function to add a row with the same number of cells with the same ids.

Comment: IDs need to be unique in your html code. If you need theses IDs to select the table cells use classes

Comment: Im using the id values  and  setting  them as keys for ajax data so they need to be the same as they are used in another part of my php script. its all working as expected now!

Comment: No, it's working because the browser is being nice.  Use a `data-` attribute instead, eg `<td data-id='task_name'` then it can be repeated.  IDs must be unique in the document (just the browser doesn't *always* enforce this - your browser doesn't, someone else's might).

Comment: I see so it works but in actual fact its a botch job!  I shall do some hoemwork. Thanks.

Comment: so in my answer below I should change from id to data- and adjust my ajax accordingly. Brilliant thanks.  Out of curiosity what are the negative impacts if I left it as it is?

Comment: Errors might vary from getting not the selected elements you would expect to your page not rendering at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer out, by removing the "td" from the each part of the selector I can specify the id's:

```
jQuery.each($('tr:last', this), function () {
        tds += '<td id='task_name' contenteditable="true"></td>';
        tds += '<td id='brief' contenteditable="true"></td>';
        tds += '<td id='assigned_to' contenteditable="true"></td>';
        tds += '<td id='hours_to_complete' contenteditable="true"></td>';
        tds += '<td id='status' contenteditable="true"></td>';
});
```